# Assign a port to a webaddress

Tags: networking, proxy, java

I'd like to give my friends a url instead of a ip:port address for connecting to my minecraft server.

Specifically I'd like to give them `minecraft.myregistereddomain.com` instead of `myregistereddomain.com:25565`.

My domain is registered through name.com

I thought about using ngnix to reverse proxy to it, something like myregistereddomain.com/minecraft but then I learned minecraft is not http, and ngnix is a simple http web server only: [See This Answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138264/nginx-proxy-pass-to-minecraft-server)

I also tried a url redirect, and assigning an A record in the form of
minecraft.myregistereddomain.com to myregistereddomain.com:25565 but name.com said this was invalid.

Clearly, I'm a bit new the world of web hosting. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've managed to do this with [SRV Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) before.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me. Respond as an answer and I'll get you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SRV Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) to do this. Basically, they point one domain towards another with the ability to also, in your case, specify a port to connect to.

SRV Records use the following format:

```
_service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port target.
```

The SRV record you might use could look like:

```
_minecraft._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 5 0 25565 example.com.
```

Comment: Note that not all clients support SRV records, so while this might work for Minecraft specifically, it isn't guaranteed to work in every situation.